# Only one active for each relationship constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

So i have this problem with my assignment.
I have two entities: Order, Gifr_cupon.
I have two tables: Orders, Gift_Cupons.

Each order can have many cupons or none. Each Cupon is bound to no or an single order. But only one cupon can be active for each order.

How to enforce this by constraint?

Heres a logical and ER view with DDL:

[image]
[image]
DLL:

```
CREATE TABLE gift_cupons (
cupon_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
order_order_id   INTEGER,
active           INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE gift_cupons ADD CONSTRAINT gift_cupon_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cupon_id 
);
ALTER TABLE gift_cupons ADD CHECK gift_cupon_check CHECK(active IS NULL OR ( active >= 0 AND active <=1 ) );

CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY ( order_id );

ALTER TABLE gift_cupons
ADD CONSTRAINT gift_cupon_order_fk FOREIGN KEY ( order_order_id )
    REFERENCES orders ( order_id );
```

Comment: Why do you allow multiple coupons per order but only one of them to be active? What does this even mean?

Comment: Customer can have many cupons, only one can be made active, so that he cannot combine the bonus from the cupons. This is just a school assignment, so its only theoretical.

Comment: Made active per order you mean?

Comment: It sounds like one customer has many coupons but an order only has one coupon? Can coupons be reused?

Comment: Customer has an order...the order can be imagined as an service...like cable, or phone bill etc. He can use cupon on this order that he recieved but only one can be active.

Comment: Still not seeing why an order has many coupons but only one of them be active

Comment: A product has many applicable coupons. A customer subscribes to a product. A customer is eligible for some coupons. A customer net has many orders. An order has up to one single coupon - ??

Comment: As I said. The order is an service that is payed monthly. There are cupons for either lower price or extra services, theres a finite number of cupons. All the cupons in the company are stored in the table "cupons". Each cupon can be bound to only one order. So for example, you are paying a cable and as a gift you may either activate 10% discount or have extra channels... Coupon types etc.. are not relevant in the example. The excersice wants me to create a constraint to enforce that for every Order_Id in coupons table, there is only one active.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why you want to store multiple coupons per order and have only one of them be active? Why does an order reference a thousand coupons it doesn't use and one that it does? Why not make the single useful coupon a property of the order?

Comment: So that a customer can have a choice and may switch between them.

Comment: So it's the customer that has the collection of coupons, and an order has an active customercouponid ?

Comment: Cupons are tied to a specific order. Customer cant use a cupon for another order. AS with the example above. Customer can pick if he has a 10% discount or extra channels if he was given these cupons for that specific order. Cupons cant be traded among customers or used on other orders.

Comment: Indeed, and if the order has a coupon id that tracks the active coupon and emsewherecin the db (not in the orders table) something else lists the coupons the customer has access to, the world is modelled and the problem is solved. I don't think an order should track a list of coupons, I think it should just track an active coupon. I think something else (customer!) should track the list of coupons available to the customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of

```
Cupon - is bound to -> Order;
Order - has active -> Cupon;

Cupon (
Id PK,
orderId FK Order.Id,
Unique ( Id, orderId) -- any superset  of PK is unique
);

Order (
Id PK
ActiveCuponId,
(Id, ActiveCuponId) FK Cupon( OrderId, Id)
);
```

See fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=596b30905d02a9e5c799b16da5fff5ab

Comment: `FK Cupon( OrderId, Id)`? A foreign key needs to point to a key on the other table, and `(OrderId, Id)` is not a key. Just make it a key and this answer will be good.

Comment: @Impaler .. Not a problem at all. Super key is a key. So just technically need to declare a unique constraint which is always true. OK, corrected

Comment: Good. Otherwise the db engine won't allow it. +1

Comment: What if cupon is not bound to an order and OrderId in Cupon is null? Will it still work?

Comment: @DavidWaldo Yes, it will. The idea is, to be Active cupon of the order, cupon first must be assigned to the order. Both `Order.ActiveCuponId` and `Cupon.OrderId` are NULLable. See the fiddle reference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ACTIVE` column from the `gift_cupons` table, and replace this state by a foreign key in the `orders` table, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE gift_cupons (
cupon_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
order_order_id   INTEGER,
);

ALTER TABLE gift_cupons ADD CONSTRAINT gift_cupon_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cupon_id 
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id INTEGER NOT NULL
active_cupon INTEGER -- nullable
);

ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY ( order_id );

ALTER TABLE gift_cupons
ADD CONSTRAINT gift_cupon_order_fk FOREIGN KEY ( order_order_id )
    REFERENCES orders ( order_id );

alter table orders
add constraint order_active_cupon_fk foreign key (active_cupon)
    references gift_cupons (cupon_id);
```