# Which is the better approach to design the tables for Client and Address on which the client has a primary address?

Tags: database-design

A client might have two addresses recorded in the database, one address is the primary, the other one is the secondary, this post is to identify the better design to address this problem.

I identified the following solutions, do you have any other ?

Solution 1:

```
Table Clients
+ name
+ surname
Table Addresses
+ line1
+ city
+ country
+ postcode
+ flag_primary
```

Solution 2:

```
Table Clients
+ name
+ surname
+ primary_address_id

Table Addresses
+ line1
+ city
+ country
+ postcode
```

Solution 3:

```
Table Clients
+ id
+ name
+ surname

Table Addresses
+ id
+ user_id
+ line1
+ city
+ country
+ postcode

Table User_Settings
+ user_id
+ address_id
```

Please explain why you believe your suggestion is the right one.

Comment: "it depends" :-)

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586988/only-one-active-for-each-relationship-constraint/56587177

Comment: In the real world, a person might have multiple addresses, and multiple people might share an address - which implies the need for a many to many relationship

Comment: hello.. I edited the question in order to add the Solution 3, may I know your thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

CLEARLY, do the solution 2.

Logical: when a client change his primary address, that doesn't change the address. This is reflected in the db schema

Corruption: there is no way you db get strange having a client with two primary address. Solution 1 can have two boolean flag to true.

Simplicity: when you change a client addres, you can do it by just a single update. For solution 1, you do 2 updates... maybe in one tricky SQL query but this is two update !

Extensibility: if one day, you want adress to be 'shareable', like not storing the same exact adress for two people living at the same place, you will not break your 'primary_address' fonctionnality, cause it's stored on user. On solution 1, it will need a refactoring.

Compliant with all 'versioning' system: client change his primary address? => client is updated => store old version or updated lines for this client.
With solution 1, you will break it or have to change the default behavior by yourself.

**Edit**: well if you edit your question after we answered it, it make our answers look silly.

Recommand you that, if you now plan to have more than one address per client, but still a primary one

```
client
    primary_address (fk to address(id))

address
    client (fk to client(id))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It seems you mentioned solution two when you wanted to mention solution one, am I wrong ? Because Solution 1 is that one with flags.

Comment: Solution 2 only allows a single address per client - that is hardly realistic.

Comment: it just depend of the context... like for government, electricity, internet provider,... you only have one address for lot of businesses.

Answer (score 0):

As there are two entities - Client & Address

An address will only exist if and only if a Client exist with that Address. So there is a dependency of **Address** entity on **Client** entity, so you can have client_id in address entity as foreign key.

You can have something like this:

```
Table Clients
+ client_id
+ name
+ surname

Table Addresses
+ line1
+ city
+ country
+ postcode
+ flag_primary
+ client_id [FOREIGN_KEY]
```

Comment: An address could be shared by multiple clients (e.g. the postal address of a company would be associated with any employee of that company)

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, a client will have more than one address and one address can be shared by multiple clients (e.g. the postal address of a company).

I would go for a many-to-many relationship between client and address with a flag indicating which address is the primary one. Or even a type ("postal", "visit", ...)

table `client`

- `id` (PK)
- `first_name`
- `last_name`

table `address`

- `id` (PK)
- `line1`
- `city`
- `postcode`
- ....

table `client_address`

- `address_id` (FK to `address`)
- `client_id` (FK to `client`)
- `is_primary` (boolean, true/false)

Depending on the actual database product, the "only one primary address per client" can be enforced with a unique constraint on the `client_address` table